# Code sign error during archiving the proejct in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, key

I am trying to build ipa for the purpose of testing using Ad Hoc. When I tried to archive this is the error I am getting

```
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain
```

I dint create any keys. Do I need to create one? Is there any good page to follow the steps? And which is the simplest way for testing iphone app?

FYI I am using xcode 4

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From [HOWTO: Obtaining your iOS Development Certificate](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action):

> In the ‘Certificates’ section of the iOS Provisioning Portal, you can
>   request individual iOS Development Certificates. All iOS applications
>   must be signed by a valid certificate before they can be run on an
>   Apple device. In order to sign applications for testing purposes, Team
>   Members need an iOS Development Certificate.
>
> A digital identity is an electronic means of identification consisting
>   of a secret "private key" and a shared "public key". This private key
>   allows Xcode to sign your iOS application binary.

Comment: Do I need to be a registered developer? When I opened the link it says access denied even though I have logged in.

Comment: Oh, yes, you need to log in with a registered developer account first.  This is also required to make the certificates and get the provisioning profiles, etc.